# How to find the Folder/path details of the file selection in ReactJs (Input type= File),

Tags: reactjs, file, input, path

I am looking for ways to find the Folder/Path details of the file selection in ReactJs,
I see all the examples concentrating on file selection only, I need to know the path details for my application.

Answer (score 0):

you can't access to file path on the users' client for some privacy/security reasons, imagine this was possible, Then web apps could track users with this argument!

**a NOTE about using ReactJs with ElectronJS:** *but if you work with ElectronJS you can do that by reading `path` of [file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object or use [dialog](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog) API*

Comment: Thanks for your response, I dont know how it is a privacy issue if they know the directory, when the input type file letting user to access the file system .

Comment: Also thanks for letting me know about ElectronJS, I will check it, in the mean time please share me the example if you have one.